# Drupal - whether it will be safe to run these 4 steps

Tags: caching, drupal, command

whether it will be safe to run these 4 steps ?

drush cr
drush updb
drush cim -y
drush cr

By safe, I mean no impact in terms of functional, performance, database behavior in Drupal

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on your codebase. Did you change configuration or did you add update hooks? What kind of configuration and what do the update hooks do?

Only in the case that you changed nothing at all a cache clear should only cause your site to take a long time to load for a few minutes.

This is why you have a develop environment or you can use your local environment with a fresh database dump from your live site to test a deploy (and drush commands).

Answer (score 0):

Technically the correct order of performing this commands is:

- drush cr
- drush cim -y
- drush cr
- drush updb -y

Saying this because if you're updating your database with changes that you've newly deployed, they won't be available until you import the configuration first.